# Flutter BoxConstraints maxWidth in CustomScrollView not working

Tags: flutter, dart, constraints, customscrollview

I am using a `CustomScrollView` and tried to limit its children's size by using `BoxConstraints` but they are simply ignored. My text expands to the width of the screen and I don't understand why.

This is my code:

```
  SliverToBoxAdapter(
    child: ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: maxWidthConstraint,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              widget.project.description,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

What am I missing here? Let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent forces it to be the full width so you can wrap it with `UnconstrainedBox` or `Align` or `Center` widget to get rid of that behavior.

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: UnconstrainedBox( // this should allow it to have its own constraints
    child: ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: maxWidthConstraint,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              widget.project.description,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: I wrapped the `Column` with a `Center` instead of the `ConstrainedBox`. Working now, thank you :)